# Consistency level ALL used while statement has consistency level TWO defined

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-2.1

We use java datastax cassandra driver `2.1.2`. Cassandra version we use is `2.0.9`.

We have statement which we build with `QueryBuilder` and we are setting consistency level to statement on `TWO` explicitly.

```
Select selectStatement =  QueryBuilder.select().from(ARTICLES);
selectStatement.where(eq(ORGANIZATION_ID, organizationId));
selectStatement.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.TWO);

final ResultSet rs = session.execute(selectStatement);
//call to all() will be removed since it is enough to iterate over result set 
//and then you get pagination for free instead of loading everything in 
//memory
List<Row> rows = rs.all();  
for (final Row row : rows) {
   //do something with Row, convert to POJO
}
```

We get exception like this:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency ALL (3 responses were required but only 2 replica responded)
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException.copy (ReadTimeoutException.java:69)
com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException (DefaultResultSetFuture.java:259)
com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedResultSet$MultiPage.prepareNextRow (ArrayBackedResultSet.java:279)
com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedResultSet$MultiPage.isExhausted (ArrayBackedResultSet.java:239)
com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedResultSet$1.hasNext (ArrayBackedResultSet.java:122)
com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedResultSet.all (ArrayBackedResultSet.java:111)
```

I know that calling `all()` on `ResultSet` makes it load all articles for organization in memory and work with it and creates load on cassandra. This will be removed as noted in comments. This can cause read timeout but I am still puzzled why in exception message there is `ALL`.

**Question** is why exception is telling that consistency level `ALL` is used when we set it to `TWO` for original statement. Is `all()` internally doing something with query and using CL `ALL` by default?

Comment: Which version o c* are you running?

Comment: We are using Cassandra 2.0.9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is almost certainly https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7947 . You are seeing an error message from failing to perform read repair. It is unrelated to your original consistency level. This is fixed in 2.1.3+.

Comment: Thanks for answer and explanation, I will increase driver version and try.

Comment: You'll have to upgrade cassandra, not the driver. Check the jira ptnapoleon posted ^^